# If $x_1,\cdots, x_n ~ N(0,\sigma^2)$ and iid and $T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$ What is the distribution of T

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was thinking using the mgf

$M_{T}(s)=E(e^{Ts})=E(e^{s\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2})=E(\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{sx_{i}^2})$

What would be next?

Answer (score 2):

> What would be next?

Next would be that the random variables $X_i$ being i.i.d., $M_T(s)=E[\mathrm e^{sX_1^2}]^n$. Then that if $Y$ is standard gaussian, then for every $u\lt1/2$,
$$
E[\mathrm e^{uY^2}]=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\mathrm e^{uy^2}\mathrm e^{-y^2/2}\mathrm dy\stackrel{(z=y\sqrt{1-2u})}{=}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1{\sqrt{1-2u}}\int\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}\mathrm dz=\frac1{\sqrt{1-2u}}.
$$
Then that, applying this to $u=s\sigma^2$ yields, for every $s\lt s_\sigma$ with $s_\sigma=1/(2\sigma^2)$,
$$
M_T(s)=(1-s/s_\sigma)^{-n/2}.
$$
Then that, for every $a\gt0$ and $s\lt s_\sigma$,
$$
\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{st}t^{a-1}\mathrm e^{-s_\sigma t}\mathrm dt\stackrel{(r=(s_\sigma-s)t)}{=}(s_\sigma-s)^{-a}\int_0^\infty r^{a-1}\mathrm e^{-r}\mathrm dr=(s_\sigma-s)^{-a}\Gamma(a).
$$
And finally that
$$
M_T(s)=\Gamma(n/2)^{-1}\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{st}t^{(n-2)/2}\mathrm e^{-s_\sigma t}\mathrm dt,
$$
hence that $T$ has a density $f_T$ defined by
$$
f_T(t)=\Gamma(n/2)^{-1}s_\sigma^{n/2}t^{(n-2)/2}\mathrm e^{-s_\sigma t}\mathbf 1_{t\gt0}.
$$
Which is the density of some [well-known distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Probability_density_function)...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The sqaure of the normal distribution is the chi squared distribution. And being a $\Gamma$ distribution with $(\frac{k}{2},2)$, you can "add" them up. Check your final answer at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).